# Learning Processing - How do I use saveBytes()?

Tags: processing

I'm having trouble with saveBytes(). When I call saveBytes(), it doesn't actually save the bytes into a file, like it should. The file is in the same folder, and is correctly named. The bytes just aren't being written into the file.

Here is my code:

```
int varOne = 0;
int varTwo = 4;
int varThree = 2;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  saveTheBytes();
}

void saveTheBytes(){
  byte[] byteArray = {(byte)varOne, (byte)varTwo, (byte)varThree}
  saveBytes("filename.txt", byteArray)
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the missing semicolons at the end of each statement in `saveTheBytes()` the code looks legit.
        One note: you're overwriting this file multiple times a second in `draw()`. Maybe you meant to do that once in `setup()` ?

Double check the filesize of your file: it should be exactly 3 bytes.

These aren't going to be visible in a text editor (as they are [ASCII characters](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `NULL`, `END OF TRANSMISSION` and `START OF TEXT`).

You should see the bytes in a with a hex editor as `0x00 0x04 0x02`.

Here's a preview using HexFiend on OSX:
[image: 00 04 02 as byes and text]